# download static/snapshot satellite data of the USA

Tags: geospatial, map

I'm looking to download satellite data with resolution good enough to see objects that are 10 meters in size (eg tiles that are 20m x 20m).  I do not care about changes over time.  I'm basically just looking at rocks and static/snapshot (one point in time) data is fine.  I don't care if the data is 20 years old or new today.

I really want to be able to download all of the data, ideally as a bunch of files/images containing zoomed in views, instead of accessing bits of data via an API.

I primarily care about the USA but would be fine with data from the whole world.  I'm not intending on using these data for financial gain, nor will I share with the public, so okay with data that has limitations around that type of usage.

Thank you so much for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the data mentioned on this [website](https://gisgeography.com/free-satellite-imagery-data-list/). It e.g. mentions Sentinel with a 10m and SPOT with a 1.5m resolution.